# Make InDesign Add Pages Automatically As You Type

Tags: adobe-indesign

How is it possible to make InDesign add new pages automatically when the text exceeds the current frame?

Yes, I know that the most simple way is to enable the `Primary Text Frame` checkbox when defining a new document, but it seems there is another way as described by David Blatner:

> Here’s the thing: by default, it only works when you are working on a text frame that is on a master page. That is, you:
>
> 1. put a text frame on the master page [then, David desribes the second option that I have mentioned above]
> 2. override that frame on a document page by either placing text into it or command-shift-clicking it (or ctrl-shift-click on windows)
> 3. type in it or edit the text so that the frame oversets
> 4. pause one or two seconds so that InDesign notices that the frame is overset

Source: https://creativepro.com/make-indesign-add-pages-automatically-as-you-type/

Could anybody explain what exactly I need to do?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here? The four steps you quote from David are exactly what you need to do to make InDesign automatically add pages. Are you looking for a way to turn a text box on a master page into a primary text box (which also means you don’t have to Cmd+Shift-click it on the page to override it, but can just type straight into it)? That’s easily done, but it’s not what your question seems to be about apart from the mention of ticking the checkbox “when defining a new document”…

Comment: (Note: David’s article is quite old, geared at CS6. David notes that, as far as he can tell, the feature is not limited to primary text frames even if that option is ticked, but works for all master page text frames. Off the top of my head, I believe this is _no longer the case_. In more recent versions of InDesign, this option does what it says and limits smart reflow specifically to _primary_ text frames.)

Comment: Have you noticed the screenshot in the linked article which shows how you need to tick *Smart Text Reflow*?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet By coincidence, I use the same CS6 version as David. I already tried what the article says, but the new new page is not created in my case for some reason, so I suppose that my understanding is not correct in some point and so I ask for alternative directions, which will be easier to follow.

Comment: @Woff, Yes, this check box is enabled.

Comment: @johnc.j. If you’re sure the option is checked, and that the text frame your text is in is an overridden master page frame (apparently – I still think the safest would be a primary text frame) and not a text frame that was drawn on the page itself, then it should work. Those are the only two things required for it to work.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "the text frame your text is in is an overridden master page frame" - The problem is that I don't understand how to ensure that this is true.

Comment: You can’t tell just by looking at it, but where did you draw the text frame? Were you on the master page when you drew it, or were you on the text page itself? If you drew it directly on the text page, it’s not a master page item and smart reflow will never apply. To make sure, you can always just make a text frame on the master page, cut the text on the text page and delete the frame it was in, then Ctrl/Cmd+Shift-click where the new frame is (on the text page) to override it and paste the text into it. That way you’re sure it’s an overridden master page item.

Comment: OK, after clicking here and there, it works. But now I wonder _why_. Ha ha